# IIS URL rewrite has a problem with non-English characters

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I set the IIS URL rewrite in my web.config of my asp.net project.
It's working well with the English alphabet in the title query string, but it doesn't work with a none English alphabet, even when I changed the title to `{UrlEncode:{R:2}}`.

```
<rule name="Rewrite to Page.aspx">
      <match url="^page/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="page.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

for example:

`http://localhost:53849/page/1/english-character` is working properly, but `http://localhost:53849/page/1/ตรวจสอบ` is not working and throws the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: Please spend time learning regular expressions. You wrote an expression that only works for English characters, so no doubt it breaks.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi I changed ([_0-9a-z-]+)  to  ([^A-Za-z0-9_]+) and now working

Answer (score 3):

You can also change it to

```
^page/([0-9]+)/(.*)
```

By the way, if the question has been solved, please post solution as answer and mark it so that it can help others.